# Failed to Load Resource error on Javascript/HTML Web App

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, raspberry-pi, magic-mirror

I am receiving a "Failed to Load Resource" error, saying:

> http://localhost:8080/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/datafeed/JANUARY22TEST.csv
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

when I am trying to load the following snippet of code.  It is for one of those Magic Mirrors.  My csv file is in the directory that I am setting, but I am unsure why it is telling me that it can't see it.  It also looks like, when I try to connect to 8080, it says connection refused.

This is on a Raspberry Pi, so is it referencing the directory correctly?

```
   getDom: function() {
        d3.text("/home/pi/MagicMirror/modules/datafeed/JANUARY22TEST.csv", function(data) {

                var parsedCSV = d3.csvParseRows(data);

                var container = d3.select("body")
                    .append("table")

                    .selectAll("tr")
                        .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                        .append("tr")

                    .selectAll("td")
                        .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                        .append("td")
                        .text(function(d) { return d; });
            });
    },
```

Comment: Try and access it directly in your browser using the localhost:8080 url. Is it working from there? If not, then you know why you're getting a 404 error.

Comment: It looks like I can't access it from the browser.  It tells me the connection is refused.  Does this mean I need to make a firewall exception, or open that port?

Comment: I'm unsure as to why exactly you're unable to access it - it COULD be a firewall issue, or it could be that your server on :8080 isn't running at all. Make sure you can access other pages on there. If you can, then it's just not seeing your requested file at the location given. If you can't, then you're having issues either connecting to, or running the server itself.

Comment: Since the Magic Mirror runs on Port 8080 could it be trying to connect back through the port to itself, and then throwing the error?

Comment: A webserver can access itself through absolute paths just fine. I'd check if it's actually running - and if so, check why you can't access it.